# Linked Server inconsistent metadata

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, azure, sqlncli

Set up a linked server between SQL 2005 and Azure.  Downloaded Native Client 10 since it is apparently needed.
Says the Connection is successful.
Receive the following in trying to retrieve or upload data:

The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "EBPCloud" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "CustomerId" (compile-time ordinal 1) of object ""my table"" was reported to have a "Incomplete schema-error logic." of 0 at compile time and 0 at run time.

The column in question is a uniqueidentifier

Comment: server options:  collation compatible-true
lazy schema validation - true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to link server from 2005 to Azure. Minimum requirement is server 2008 R2